# The meaning of "I'd say"

Tags: meaning

Could you please tell me what is the meaning of "I'd say"?
I know it means "l would say" but I do n't know it's meaning.

Comment: It depends on context... it doesn't have one meaning... Can you give us an example where it has confused you?

Comment: Jack: who was he, easygoing, disturbing, or basically a good person?   Hani: "I'd say, he was not bad."

Comment: In your example, and very often, 'My opinion is that ...'.

Comment: It is synonymous to *I reckon*, *in my opinion* and such phrases

Comment: @Catija - _You'd say tomāto, I'd say tomäto_... :-)

Answer (score 1):

"Would" is what is called a *modal auxiliary verb*, sometimes informally called a *helping verb*.  The function of a modal auxiliary is to change the sense of the modified verb, that is, change its *mode*.

The function of "would" is to make the modified verb conditional: if [something], then I would [something].  Usually the condition is implied, so...

If [something], then I'd [say, he was not bad].

What is the something in your example?  It's simply a way of being polite, and implying e.g.:

If [you care to hear my opinion], then I'd say he was not bad.

or

If [I may be so bold as to express an opinion], then I'd say he was not bad.

etc.

Comment: Other possible conditions might be "If my information is reliable," or "if my judgement is good."  As @Catija mentions above, the context should clarify the implied condition.

Comment: Glad you found if useful, @hooshmand.  :)